# Unit testing, mocking and unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, mocking, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

There's a class under test which currently accepts a `unique_ptr< Interface >&&` in it's constructor,  to express that it wants to take single ownership of an Interface implementation. Problems arise when wanting to test this class using a mocked `Interface` though: the mocking framework (HippoMocks) gives me only `Interface*` which I do not own, hence cannot delete.

I had the same problem before when testing classes taking `const shared_ptr< Interface >&` as arguments, but fixed that by providing a custom no-op deleter:

```
template< class T >
void NoDelete( T* )
{
}

  //create a shared_ptr without effective deleter
template< class T >
std::shared_ptr< T > mock_shared( T* t )
{
  return std::shared_ptr< T >( t, NoDelete< T > );
}

Interface* iface = mocks.GetMeAMock< Interface >();
DoStuffWithSharedPtrOfInterface( mock_shared< Interface >( iface ) );
```

A similar fix for unique_ptr doesn't really work out because the deleter is a template argument:

```
template< class T >
struct NoDelete
{
  void operator ()( T* )
  {
  }
};

  //oops this is totally useless since std::unique_ptr< T, NoDelete< T > >
  //is not quite the same type as std::unique_ptr< T >
template< class T >
std::unique_ptr< T, NoDelete< T > > mock_unique( T* t )
{
  return std::unique_ptr< T, NoDelete< T > >( t, NoDelete< T >() );
}
```

Is there a workaround for this? Or should I not be using unique_ptr here in the first place?

**update**
I gave this a go; should work but sizeof( ptr ) is now 8, hard to tell what impact that has.

```
  //use CustomUniquePtr::type instead of uniqe_ptr
template< class T >
struct CustomUniquePtr
{
  typedef typename std::unique_ptr< T, void (*) ( T* ) > type;
}

  //use everywhere
template< class T >
CustomUniquePtr< T >::type make_unique( T* p )
{
  return CustomUniquePtr< T >::type( p, Delete< T > );
}

  //use when mocking, doe not delete p!
template< class T >
CustomUniquePtr< T >::type mock_unique( T* p )
{
  return CustomUniquePtr< T >::type( p, NoDelete< T > );
}
```

Comment: "to express that it wants to take single ownership of an Interface implementation. " It should take a `unique_ptr` by value to express that, not by `&&`.

Comment: "the mocking framework gives me only Interface* which I do not own, hence cannot delete." Can you not change the mocking framework to let you own it? If your interface requires ownership, then your mocking framework needs to *test* ownership. Otherwise, you're not really testing it.

Comment: @NicolBolas good point about the value, I will leave that out since it's of no use for the question; the pointers returned by the mocking framework do not point to anything allocated using standard new/malloc/whatever, it's just fiddling with the vtable so it's not something that can be owned

Comment: Hey man. Please, consider changing the best answer to Thomas's answer. He is the author of the library (as far as I understand). And looks like his answer best suits your question. Community will benefit from this :)

Comment: @SergeyKrusch done. Must have overlooked that answer as it was posted months after the rest..

Comment: Cool :) You rock! Upvoted couple of your answers =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hippomock already provides a solution to this problem. If you have an interface with a virtual destructor then all you need to do is to register an expectation for the destructor. The mock is not destroyed by a call to its destructor as it is a mock destructor, but an expectation for the call to the destructor must be set.

```
MockRepository mocks;
// create the mock
std::unique_ptr<IFoo> foo( mocks.Mock<IFoo>() );

// register the expectation for the destructor
mocks.ExpectCallDestructor( foo.get() );

// call to mocks destructor ok, mock not destroyed
foo.reset( nullptr );
```

Comment: This seems like the preferred answer to me as well, however it did not work in my case w/ shared_ptr. I did not investigate why.

Answer (score 7):

`shared_ptr` stores its deleter on the heap along with the other bookkeeping data (refcount etc.); `unique_ptr` has no heap overhead so the deleter has to be stored in the object and becomes part of the type.

You could template the constructor on `Deleter` and convert the `unique_ptr` to a `shared_ptr` to erase the deleter type.

Better (depending on the size of the interface) would be to provide a proxy `Interface` object that forwards to the mocked `Interface *`.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of several options, in no particular order:

- In the test code (and **only** in the test code, you don't want this in your application) specialize `default_delete<Interface>` to not actually delete anything. This will then mean that `unique_ptr<Interface>` never deletes the object it owns, which may not be desirable if you have `unique_ptr<Interface>` objects that should delete the owned objects even in the tests.
- Create an implementation of `Interface` that forwards everything to an instance provided to its constructor. You could then dynamically allocate an instance in the tests that forwards to the mock-framework-provided interface.
- Change the mock framework to dynamically allocate the interface so it can be deleted.
- Change your code to use a `std::shared_ptr` so you can pass a custom deleter. This loses the "unique ownership" property though.
- Change your code to use a custom smart pointer that deletes or not depending on construction parameters. This could just be a wrapper around a `unique_ptr`, with a "delete or not" flag. In assignments/destruction calls if the flag is set to "do not delete" then just call `release()` on the wrapped `unique_ptr` rather than allowing it to delete the object. A custom pointer type has less familiarity to users than a standard one, and the flag will take up space.
- Use a type generator like you have in the "update", so everywhere says `CustomUniquePtr<T>::type`, and then have the type generator add the deleter. The downside here is that the user code must know about the deleter to create new instances of the type from a raw pointer. This means that user code cannot easily create an implementation of your `Interface` (even a simple one that just logs calls and forwards them on) without also knowing about the deleter.

There  may of course be other options.

Comment: ... and +bounty for getting me started

Comment: A lambda for the shared_ptr case would be: `shared_ptr<IFoo>(Mocks.Mock<IFoo>(), [](IFoo*){});`  Compatible w/ VS 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Of all options given in the answers the most suitable one is definitely modifying the mock framework, since I can then just continue to use plain `unique_ptr`. I couldn't figure out how to make it dynamically allocate the mock instances but as it turns out I can make it mock `delete` itself. It's pretty hacky but it does seem to work ok.

Basically hippomocks alters the vtable directly, making entries point to functions checking expectations etc. Now, as far as I know on MSVC the first entry in the vtable for a class with a virtual destructor is the scalar deleting destructor. Which gets invoked when calling `delete ptr`. And, which normally is compiler generated and calls the destructor. Hence altering the vtable and making the first entry point to something else, a no-op, solves this issue.

This is the code added to MockRepository, it's just a copy of one of the `RegisterExpect_` functions altered ro always use a `void(void*)` signature:

```
template< int X >
void NoOp( void* )
{
}

  //make first vtable entry point to NoOp
template< int X, typename Z2 >
void DeleteExpect( Z2 *mck )
{
  const int funcIndex = 0; //index of scalar deleting destructor
  void (MockRepository::*mfp)(void*) = &MockRepository::NoOp< X >;
  BasicRegisterExpect( reinterpret_cast<mock<Z2> *>( mck ),
   funcIndex, reinterpret_cast<void (base_mock::*)()>( mfp ), X );
}

#define MockDelete( obj ) DeleteExpect< __COUNTER__ >( obj )
```

and here's how it's used:

```
MockRepository mocks;
Interface* p = mocks.InterfaceMock< Interface >();
mocks.MockDelete( p );

mocks.InterfaceMock< DataStitcher >( std::unique_ptr< Interface >( p ) );
```